# How do I know whether there is error when publishing message using JCSMP?

Tags: solace

I have the following producer:

```
XMLMessageProducer producer = session.getMessageProducer(new JCSMPStreamingPublishEventHandler() {
@Override
public void handleError(String messageID, JCSMPException cause, long timestamp) {
    logger.error("Error occurred when sending message {} ", messageID, cause);
}

// This method is only invoked for persistent and non-persistent
// messages.
@Override
public void responseReceived(String messageID) {
    logger.info("Response received for message {} ", messageID);
}
});
```

When calling `producer.send()` to publish a message to a topic, how do I know whether there is any error since `responseReceived()` is not invoked for Direct messaging?  As the message is published asynchronously, When will `handleError()` of `JCSMPStreamingPublishEventHandler` be called?  How long should I wait before we can conclude that there is no error in publishing the message?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> When calling `producer.send()` to publish a message to a topic, how do
>   I know whether there is any error since `responseReceived()` is not
>   invoked for Direct messaging?

From the [documentation](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Solace_Messaging_Platform_Feature_Guide/Solace_Messaging_Overview.html#ww200141), Direct messaging provides a reliable—but not guaranteed—delivery of messages from the Solace message bus to consuming clients. They are usually used when extremely high message rates and extremely low latency are required. The trade off is that they can also be discarded when congestion or system failures are encountered. This is why there is no acknowledgements for sending of Direct messages.

> As the message is published asynchronously, When will `handleError()` of
>   `JCSMPStreamingPublishEventHandler` be called? How long should I wait
>   before we can conclude that there is no error in publishing the
>   message?

For Direct messages, there will be no acknowledgements of successful publish. When `JCSMPSession.send()` returns, it means that the API has written the data to the TCP send buffer. System failures such as network disconnects that happen after will not be detected, and the message can be lost.

For Guaranteed messages, messages are only guaranteed to be spooled on the appliance/VMR when `responseReceived()` is invoked. If an error occurs, `handleError()` will be invoked.

Comment: I just tested that handleError() is called when I published to a topic with invalid ACL, as shown below: SEVERE: Error occurred when sending message 0 
((Client name: NCS-060613KS01/55284/#000b0001   Local addr: 10.70.202.136:60541   Remote addr: 192.168.204.119:55443) - )  com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPErrorResponseException: 403: Publish ACL Denied - Topic 'ccs1/topic12' [Subcode:28]

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I've overlooked that. Editing answer shortly.